# Can't add Javascript Game to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I'm trying to make a HTML5/Javascript game the phaser online editor. I finished the game in the preview and everything works and I downloaded it as a .JS file. I now want to attach it to a .html file so I can play it on my own website but I can't seem to attach the .js file to the .html file using the:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

If you could help me out soon that would be great.

Comment: Javascript's file extension should be `js`. Change the file name to `file.js` and also inside the html code make sure you have `src="file.js"`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check your file extensions- `"script.js"` not `"file.html"` is what you need inside of your html file to ensure that it can find your javascript game.

```
src="script.js"
```

should do the trick!
Perhaps this will help as well- https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/518949bb96913300dd000fc3

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see Dekel has commented pretty much the exact same- skidds this is your answer.